# Why hardcoding wallet addresses into the code of contract considered bad?

Tags: solidity, addresses, configuration

Why hardcoding wallet addresses into the code of contract considered bad?

And what is the workaround for that?

I've not found any information in the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you miss or lose private key of that wallets or 12 key words of that accounts then all ETH that send to that accounts from this contract will be lost, so a good solution is to add some functions to the contract to set those addresses every time when you need to